# Cannot get texture to appear using OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics

On my windows computer using opengl 4.5 and I cannot seem to get my texture to appear on screen. All I receive is a black screen. For my code, I first developed a small Vector class to house all vertex attribute information:

Vector3D.h

```
struct Position
{
    Position();
    Position(float x, float y, float z);
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

Position::Position()
{}

Position::Position(float x, float y, float z) :
    x(x), y(y), z(z)
{}

struct Color
{
    GLubyte r;
    GLubyte g;
    GLubyte b;
    GLubyte a;
};

struct TextureCoordinate
{
    float u;
    float v;
};

struct Vector3D
{
    Vector3D();
    Vector3D(float x, float y, float z);

    Position position;
    Color color;
    TextureCoordinate textCoordinate;

    void setUV(float u, float v);
};

Vector3D::Vector3D()
{}

Vector3D::Vector3D(float x, float y, float z) :
    position(x, y, z)
{}

void Vector3D::setUV(float u, float v)
{
    this->textCoordinate.u = u;
    this->textCoordinate.v = v;
}
```

I then have a sprite class, through which I Initialize vertex attributes using Init() function:

Sprite.cpp

```
void Sprite::Init(float x, float y, float width, float height)
{
    this->x = x;
    this->y = y;
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;

    if (vboID == 0)
        glGenBuffers(1, &vboID);

    Vector3D vertexData[6]{
        Vector3D {x + width, y + height, 1.0f},
        Vector3D {x, y + height, 1.0f },
        Vector3D {x, y, 1.0f},
        Vector3D {x, y, 1.0f},
        Vector3D {x + width, y, 1.0f},
        Vector3D {x + width, y + height, 1.0f},
    };

    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        vertexData[i].color.r = 0;
        vertexData[i].color.g = 155;
        vertexData[i].color.b = 200;
    };

    vertexData[0].setUV(1.0f, 1.0f);
    vertexData[1].setUV(0.0f, 1.0f);
    vertexData[2].setUV(0.0f, 0.0f);
    vertexData[3].setUV(0.0f, 0.0f);
    vertexData[4].setUV(1.0f, 0.0f);
    vertexData[5].setUV(1.0f, 1.0f);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertexData), vertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

I then have the draw function in sprite class which obviously rebinds to correct VBO and draws image:

Sprite.cpp

```
void Sprite::Draw()
{
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);

    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vector3D), (void*)offsetof(Vector3D, position));
    glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(Vector3D), (void*)offsetof(Vector3D, textCoordinate));

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6);

    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
}
```

Finally, I call everything above within my main function here (I'm also using SDL and the image loading library stb):

main.cpp

```
int main(int agrc, char** argv)
{
    window.Initialize();
    playerSprite.Init(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    GameState gamestate{ GameState::PLAY };

    SDL_Event evnt;

    int32 x, y, currentChannels;
    int32 forceChannels = 4;
    uchar8* imageData = 0;
    imageData = stbi_load("CharImage.png", &x, &y, &currentChannels, forceChannels);

    if (imageData == nullptr)
    {
        LOG("ERROR: Could not load image file!");
    };

    GLuint texture;
    glGenTextures(1, &texture);
    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, x, y, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, imageData);
    glTextureParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTextureParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTextureParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTextureParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);


    Blz::OpenGL::ShaderProgram colorShaderProgram;
    colorShaderProgram.Compile();
    colorShaderProgram.Link();
    colorShaderProgram.Bind();

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1);

    while (gamestate != GameState::EXIT)
    {
        unsigned int startTime = SDL_GetTicks();

        //Game Logic Update
        while (SDL_PollEvent(&evnt))
        {
            switch (evnt.type)
            {
            case SDL_QUIT:
                gamestate = GameState::EXIT;

            default:
                break;
            }
        }

        window.ClearBuffers();

        playerSprite.Draw();

        window.SwapBuffers();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Also, here are my shaders:

Vertex Shader

```
#version 430

layout(location=0) in vec3 vertexPosition;
layout(location=1) in vec2 textCoord;

out vec2 TextureCoord;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(vertexPosition, 1.0f);
    TextureCoord = textCoord;
};
```

Fragment Shader

```
#version 430

out vec4 daColor;
in vec2 TextureCoord;

uniform sampler2D basicTexture;

void main()
{
    vec4 texel = texture(basicTexture, TextureCoord);
    daColor = texel;
};
```

Comment: Review that wrong number `sizeof(vertexData)`used at `glBufferData()`. It must be the size in bytes of data passed to glBufferData.

Comment: While sizeof(vertexData) returns 144 which is the number of bytes within the array correct?

Comment: 144 is the size of the struct, not the whole array of data. GL knows nothing about your structures, glBufferData gets only bytes. It's up to you to compute the sizes depending on your data layout. Also, in the same matter, review how to you read buffers (glVertexAttribPointer)

Comment: @Ripi2 `struct Vector3D` has 6 floats which gives 6*4 = 24 bytes of length. Using a vector of 6 elements, we have a total of 144 bytes

Comment: Well I will say that previously I had sent down my vertex positions with color color data to opengl using the same code above and got a square to appear with the correct color displaying. That makes me think glbufferdata and glvertexattribpointer were setup correctly?

Comment: And the size of the struct, Vector3D, would be 24 (3 position floats, 4 color bytes, and 2 texture coordinate floats) - (3x4) + (4x1) + (2x4) = 24 bytes for struct.

Answer (score -1):

Its times like these that I wish there was a better alternative to cross platform graphics programming as openGL really is a mess. The reason my image wasn't showing up was because I was setting my parameters with:

glTextureParameteri()

instead of the apparently correct:

glTexParameteri()

..................

Comment: The two functions do the same thing, just not in the same way. `glTextureParameter` is a GL 4.5 DSA function that takes the *texture* to modify. It doesn't affect the bound texture. By contrast, `glTexParameter` operates on the bound texture, not a given texture. The only "mess" here is using the wrong function for the job you're trying to do.

Comment: No, that is a very poor naming convention. To have two functions that do different things be named that similarly is a design flaw if I've ever seen one. It leads to bugs like the one I just had

Comment: But they *don't do different things*. They both set parameters on textures; you can pass them the *exact same* second and third parameters. The only difference between them is how you provide that texture that they set the parameter on. In C++, these would be function overloads.

Comment: Well then why not glModfiyTexture()? Or something along those lines. Would make things clearer I believe.

Comment: Because, as shocking as it may be to believe (and I'm being serious here), OpenGL actually does have a [reasonably consistent function naming convention](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Nomenclature#Function_names_and_objects). For certain definitions of "reasonably consistent", of course ;)